# .NET 3.5 Web Application - Porting to 64Bit - Potential issues

Tags: .net, 64-bit, migration, 32-bit, porting

I have an existing ASP.net 3.5 web application.
This is tested and working in a 32 bit environment.
There is a plan to move this application to a 64 bit environment.

As a first step, the plan is to compile the entire application in "Any CPU" 
Is anyone aware of any plan / checklists that can be used in porting from 32-bit to 64-bit?

As the hardware is still in procurement, it will be a while before the actual system testing will start and hence we want to try and minimize the amount of issues that come up during the actual system testing.

\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article on migrating from 32bit to 64bit with .Net.  Contains issues, things to watch out for, and what the framework promises. (I never trust any framework's guarantee..it's always a strongly worded promise in the best of times :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx

Comment: Thanks Caladain..this is exactly what i was looking for! My googling skills seems to be deteriorating :-) I just could not find that one!!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: get hold of a cheap 64 bit laptop or desktop, and start testing on that. You don't need a full meaty server to start doing smoke tests.

Secondly: do you perform *any* native interop (e.g. using a COM component)? That's where I'd expect *potential* errors.

Comment: No direct usage of any COM components. But what with the application using different framework for various things, i would not be surprised at all to find some wrapped COM components being used someplace. Getting a cheap 64 bit machine for testing = next step! Thanks!