# Differences between 32 and 64-bit .NET (4) applications

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

What are the differences between 32 and 64-bit .NET (4) applications?

Often 32-bit applications have problems running on 64-bit machines and conversely. I know I can declare an integer as int32 and int64 (certainly int64 on 32-bit systems make problems). Are there other differences between programming an 32 OR 64-bit or a both 32 AND 64-bit compatible application?

Comment: this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102765/net-3-5-web-application-porting-to-64bit-potential-issues

Comment: possible duplicate of [64 bits stuff for C# development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889941/64-bits-stuff-for-c-development)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Some differences:

1. 32-bit and 64-bit applications can only load DLLs of the same bitness. This can be an issue for managed projects if your platform target is "Any CPU" and you reference or [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) 32-bit native DLLs. The issue arises when your "Any CPU" program runs on a 64-bit machine, since your application runs as a 64-bit process. When it tries to load the 32-bit native DLL dependency, it will throw an exception ([`BadImageFormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx)) and likely crash.
2. There are also filesystem and registry issues. A [WOW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) process that tries to read from `C:\Program Files` will end up getting redirected to `C:\Program Files (x86)` unless it first disables Windows filesystem redirection (see [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743(VS.85).aspx)).  For versions of Windows before Windows 7, there were also registry reflection issues that were similar to the filesystem redirection issues mentioned above. The MSDN article *[Registry Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235(VS.85).aspx)* explains it well.
3. Platform-specific types like `IntPtr` will have different sizes. This could be an issue in code that assumes a fixed size (serialization, marshaling).
4. There are separate physical directories for the 32- and 64-bit files in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). For my system, they are at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64`.
5. The virtual address space size of 32- and 64-bit applications is different. For 32-bit applications, the size is either 2 GB (default) or 3 GB (with [4GT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx) enabled).  For 64-bit applications, the size is 8 TB. The 32-bit address space can be a limitation for very large applications.
6. A little more obscure, but a lot of interprocess [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) calls won't work between a 32- and 64-bit process. For example, a 32-bit process can fail when trying to call [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) on a 64-bit process. The same goes for `WriteProcessMemory`, `EnumProcessModules`, and a lot of similar methods. This can be seen in C# applications if you try to enumerate the modules of a 64-bit application from a 32-bit application using the [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx) API.

Comment: Great answer! Q: Isn't `IntPtr` the *only* safe platform-dependent type?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I think you should not have any problems with managed code.

Potential problems can come from unmanaged code. For example, because variable sizes are different in 32-bit and 64-bit systems, pointers are different, etc. For example, the size of the int variable in C/C++ depends on the system. As for managed code as already mentioned, [WoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows) can handle that.

Answer (score 3):

x64 managed code will use [Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) for double/float computation instead of x87 [Floating Point Unit (FPU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) when using x86 managed code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, I would like to add one more thing: we can run software of 32-bit system on 64 but conversely is not possible!