# C# Modal Popup does not appear in some devices after publishing my website although it appears locally

Tags: c#, web, modalpopup

C# Modal popup appears locally correctly But when I published my website--> modal popup doesn't appear in my PC But it works fine and appears in some other PCs..

this is the website:
http://training.3adda.com/training/pg_Register_OL.aspx
After selecting category-->show all courses related then select course --> show modal popup with course description

I don't know where the problem is...in website or server i published or my pc!!

please help...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website seems to check for the `Personal Information` requirements before spitting out the Modal. Also I found some of the following bugs:

- Modal shows only if the mandatory fields are entered.
- Mandatory fields accept any value as answers. For eg., it doesn't check the formatting of email nor a proper telephone number.
- The section field in Modal appears a bit cluttered. It can be listed out as bullets using:

  `string str = "\u2022 First Line." + System.Environment.NewLine + "\u2022 Second Line.";`

where `\u2022` is the ASCII character for the bullet point symbol.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help...yes Modal should be appeared only if personal info entered...
But How this comments you refer affect in modal appear in some devices and does not appear in others ?

Comment: The architecture (32 or 64-bit) strikes me a source of the error. Does this occur with all strings? Do you notice anything with trivial strings (eg. sending a single null byte)?

Comment: The architecture (32 bit)..yes i accept empty string values in some fields not all

Comment: I meant to say the architectural differences between the computers might be a source of error.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540795/6513921) for further emphasis over my comment.

Comment: Ooh! sorry for misunderstanding...- My PC is 32 bit and modal work locally and does not in published. - I tried to browse the website from another PC 32 bit and find that i works fine and modal popup appears correctly in published....thanks you help

Comment: @Micheal D any help

Comment: I am sorry, I am out of ideas.